# Definition of dispatch_queue_t as strong

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I saw the following line:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t filterMainQueue;
```

Why is declared an instance of dispatch_queue_t, which is not an object, as strong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is totally a good practice. I want to notice that **since** OS X Mountain Lion and iOS 6.0 all GCD and XPC objects in iOS/ OS X runtimes are **now** treated as Objective-C objects by `ARC` and they are not primitives now so they will be memory-managed the same way as usual Objective-C objects. That's why from now you should declare them as `strong`.

You can check this yourself in `object.h` :

```
#define DISPATCH_DECL(name) OS_OBJECT_DECL_SUBCLASS(name, dispatch_object)
```

This fact is also **stated** in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html): 
  `iOS 6 and later—Dispatch objects (including queues) are Objective-C objects, and are retained and released automatically.
  OS X 10.8 and later—Dispatch objects (including queues) are Objective-C objects, and are retained and released automatically. 
  Earlier versions—Dispatch objects are custom objects. You must handle the reference counting manually`

And also from the comments in `object.h`:

```
 * By default, dispatch objects are declared as Objective-C types when building
 * with an Objective-C compiler. This allows them to participate in ARC, in RR
 * management by the Blocks runtime and in leaks checking by the static
 * analyzer, and enables them to be added to Cocoa collections.
 * See <os/object.h> for details.
```

Comment: Hi, your claim is based on the name of the `define` `OS_OBJECT_DECL_SUBCLASS`? Because it is a subclass, we can assume that they are now objects? What would be `name` and `dispatch_object` in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig My claim not only based on this. Please see my edits. It is also stated in docs so it is more authoritative fact that my own `object.h` research

Comment: I get a `property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type` error even though I'm using OS X 10.10 SDK.

Comment: @Rivera This behaviour is controlled by the `OS_OBJECT_HAVE_OBJC_SUPPORT` macro, which is defined in <os/object.h> header. Make sure it is set to 1. And more important: check if your deployment target is actually set to iOS 6.0 or higher.

Comment: It was for a library, so the deployment target could be either iOS 5+ or 6+. I ended with this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/24846028/1049134 Thanks!