# Strong dispatch_queue_t in CocoaPods library

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, cocoapods

In a library that may be built with an iOS 5.x/OS X 10.7 deployment target or with a newer one I had a problem for properly defining a `dispatch_queue_t` property.

For the most part I could solve it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24846028/1049134):

```
#if OS_OBJECT_HAVE_OBJC_SUPPORT // == 1 not really needed
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t loggerQueue; // An Objective-C object
#else
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_queue_t loggerQueue; // A C pointer
#endif
```

This works when manually creating a static library or when including the file directly in a project.

When this code is added to a CocoaPods library however it breaks for iOS 6+/OS X 10.8+ deployment targets.
CocoaPods properly sets the deployment targets and the compiler do sets `OS_OBJECT_HAVE_OBJC_SUPPORT == 1` and chooses the `strong` definition. I get however the iOS 5.x/OS X 10.7 error:

> Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type

I tried comparing the resulting environment variables between CocoaPods and the static library but there's nothing that seems suspicious.

For now I have patched it by disabling the `strong` definition altogether when building with CocoaPods:

```
#if OS_OBJECT_HAVE_OBJC_SUPPORT && !defined(COCOAPODS)
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t loggerQueue; // Always disabled
#else
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_queue_t loggerQueue;
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Seems](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/pull/420#issuecomment-67561238) like older CocoaPods was redefining `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC` breaking `OS_OBJECT_HAVE_OBJC_SUPPORT`.

We got this [fixed](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Classes/DDLog.h#L26) by checking `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC` and using a newer CocoaPods.