# What is the default thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

In `iOS`, we have `GCD` and `Operation` to handle concurrent programming.

looking into `GCD` we have `QoS` classes, and they're simple and straight forward, this question is about why `DispatchQueue.main.async` is commonly used to asynchronies *X* tasks in  the `Main Thread`.

So when we usually handle updating something in the `UI` we usually use that function since to prevent any irresponsiveness from the application.

makes me think is writing code inside the `UIViewController` usually executed in the main thread ?

but also knowing that `callback & completionHandler` usually execute without specifying on what thread they are in, and the `UI`  never had a problem with that !! so it is on the background ?

How Swift handles this ? and what thread  am i writing on by default without specifying anything  ?

Comment: while you also can be certain iOS makes all lifecycle / user interaction related calls on the main thread, usually you can be certain in one more thing: a callback or completion closure (or block) __might not be__ invoked on a main thread – unless the API specifies the behaviour explicitly (e.g. _executed on main thread_, _executed concurrently_, etc...).

Comment: how the compiler decide that ? normally and writing in `UIViewController` by default execute the code in the main thread ?

Comment: I believe every class that starts with UI, like UIViewController is by default  executed on the main thread, what I'm not sure is that if I create an NSObject for exemple, is it executed on the main thread aswell ?

Comment: @Mathias good point

Comment: This depends on where the `NSObject` is created. For example, if you are creating this in the @IBAction function for a button click, yes it is created in the main thread. On the other hand, if you call from a completion handler of a URLSession request which returns in a background thread, it will be created in a background thread (as long as you didn't dispatch to main thread using `DispatchQueue.main.async`). The context(thread) in which you write your code will determine on what thread the code executes

Comment: "is writing code inside the UIViewController usually executed in the main thread?" What do you mean by mentioning "insider the UIViewController"? "but also knowing that callback & completionHandler usually execute without specifying on what thread they are in" who said that?! Do you know how things implemented in the background? "and what thread am i writing on by default without specifying anything ?" Main Thread.

Comment: @AhmadF inside the class, i don't specify any thread they work on and never seen such code, so Main thread is the default

Comment: @AhmadF how the callbacks are handled automatically not causing any problem to the UI ?

Comment: Indeed it is, the main thread. Depends on what do you mean by "callbacks", don't consider that using a method from the UIKit -for instance- with a callback means that its not including `DispatchQueue.main.async` in it.

Comment: its not included, lets talk about completion handlers

Comment: How the compiler recognize that he doesn't have to wait for the CompH , what is the mechanic behind that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Since there are more than one question here, let's attempt to answer them one by one.*

> why DispatchQueue.main.async is commonly used to asynchronies X tasks
>   in the Main Thread.

Before mentioning a direct answer, make sure that you don't have confusion of understanding:

- Serial <===>  Concurrent.
- Sync <===> Async.

Keep in mind that `DispatchQueue.main` is *serial* queue. Using `sync` or `async` has nothing to do with determining *serialization* or *currency* of a queue, instead they refer to how the task is handled. Thus saying `DispatchQueue.main.async` means that:

> returns control to the current queue right after task has been sent to
>   be performed on the different queue. It doesn't wait until the task is
>   finished. It doesn't block the queue.
>
> <sub>cited from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44324968/5501940 (I'd recommend to check it.)</sub>

In other words, `async` means: this will happen on the main thead and update it when it is finished. That's what makes what you said:

> So when we usually handle updating something in the UI we usually use
>   that function since to prevent any irresponsiveness from the
>   application.

seems to be sensible; Using `sync` -instead of `async`- will block the main.

---

> makes me think is writing code inside the UIViewController usually
>   executed in the main thread ?

First of all: By default, without specifying which thread should execute a chunk of code it would be the main thread. However your question seems to be unspecific because inside a `UIViewController` we can call functionalities that are not executed on the main thread by specifying it.

---

> but also knowing that callback & completionHandler usually execute
>   without specifying on what thread they are in, and the UI never had a
>   problem with that !! so it is on the background ?

"knowing that callback & completionHandler usually execute without specifying on what thread they are in" No! You have to specify it. A good real example for it, actually that's how [Main Thread Checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker) works.

I believe that there is something you are missing here, when dealing when a built-in method from the `UIKit` -for instance- that returns a completion handler, we can't see that it contains something like `DispatchQueue.main.async` when calling the completion handler; So, if you didn't execute the code inside its completion handler inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` so we should assume that it handles it for you! It doesn't mean that it is not implemented somewhere.

Another real-world example, Alamofire! When calling

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    // what is going on here work has to be async on the main thread
}
```

That's why you can call it without facing any "hanging" issue on the main thread; It doesn't mean its not handled, instead it means they handle it for you so you don't have to worry about it.