# calling two functions after each other using DispatchQueue / DispatchGroup

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency

TL;DR see below for a code example of the problem.

I have two functions `async update()` that updates some data on the server and waits for the response. I have the option to provide a callback or make the function async and wait for the response. The second function `fetch()` lives in a different class (actually a different @StateObject, i.e. ObservableObject class - I'm using SwiftUI).

**The function `fetch()` is triggered from a view, but it should "wait" for the `update()` function to have finished (if there is one running) before executing.**

I want to keep the two class instances -where these functions are part of- separate. Thus I cannot explicitly use callback or alike. After searching and discovering `DispatchQueue`, `DispatchGroup`, `Task`, `OperationQueue` and concepts of synchronous/asynchronous, serial/concurrent I am quite confused on what to use since many of them seem to be very similar tools.

1. **DispatchQueue (& Task)**

   At first I thought DispatchQueue was the way to go since the [docs](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) seem to describe exactly what I need: *"... Dispatch queues execute tasks either serially or concurrently. ..."*
   The DispatchQueue.main is serial so I thought simply executing both function calls like this would wait for the `update()` to finish if there was one started anywhere in my app and `fetch()` would run afterwards. But apparently:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.example = await self.update()
   }
   ```

   That throws an error:

   > Cannot pass function of type '() async -> ()' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

   That already seems weird to me because of its name `DispatchQueue.main.`**`async`**. I can avoid this by wrapping the call in a `Task {}` but then I suppose it gets run on a different thread, as it did not finish the `Task` before running the `fetch()` function. Thus it was no longer serial:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       Task {
           print("1")
           try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000_000)
           print("2")
       }
       Task {
           print("3")
       }
   }

   // prints 1,3, ..., 2
   ```

   Using `DispatchQueue.main.sync` could seem more of what I need according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44325307/9739903), but I get the error:

   > No exact matches in call to instance method 'sync'

   **Is there a way to use `DispatchQueue` to accomplish my goal?**
   (I also tried creating my own queue with the same result as using the global main queue. I would want to use an asynchronous function and block any other function on this queue until after finishing execution)
2. **DispatchGroup**

   Next I tried using `DispatchGroup` as shown [here](https://www.donnywals.com/sequencing-tasks-with-dispatchgroup/) but was already thrown off by having to pass around this `DispatchGroup()` instance to reference in ***both*** classes. ***Is it the only way to accomplish my goal? Could I avoid passing one single object to both classes at initalisation?***
3. **OperationQueue**

   After reading further I stumbled across `OperationQueue` [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/operations/). Again, this seems to solve my issue, but I once again have to pass this `OperationQueue` object to both classes.

Can someone explain the distinguishing differences of these approaches in relation to my problem? **Which one is the "proper" way to do it?** I would assume not having to pass around some objects is easier, but then how can I use a global `DispatchQueue` to serially execute some async functions?

---

Here a MRE, after clicking *"start long task"* and right away *fetch* the console should read: *"1","2","these would be some results"*

```swift
import SwiftUI

class Example1ManagerState: ObservableObject {
    func update() async {
        print("1")
        try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000_000)
        print("2")
    }
}

class Example2ManagerState: ObservableObject {
    func fetch() {
        print("these would be some results")
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    
    @StateObject var ex1 = Example1ManagerState()
    @StateObject var ex2 = Example2ManagerState()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task {
                await ex1.update()
            }
        } label: {
            Text("start long task")
        }
        
        Button {
            ex2.fetch()
        } label: {
            Text("fetch")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DispatchQueue`, `Task` and `async await` should never be mixed. There is no reason to do this and they are incompatible. Both options are incorrect. Check out Meet async/await in Swift from #wwdc21
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132 The older "Queue"/"Group" options deal with threading and the newer concurrency deals with "Actor" You should also look into Dependency injection this can help centralizing code and minimize the passing around.

Comment: @loremipsum alright, thanks for clearing that up. I will watch the wwdc.
But I am still curious if it is not at all possible to use only queues. As they say in the video a synchronous task blocks the thread, but couldn't I use this to my advantage? like creating a new thread (queue) and using it only to start the update() synchronously? then when I start the fetch() anywhere it will only execute after update() has finished because only then is the thread free...

Comment: You can use queues or async await, not both. Also Dependency injection is likely what you need for cross class communication or notifications is another option.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks. could you provide a code snipped for the notification case you mention?
While watching WWDC a question came up: what is the difference in the result between async functions (i.e. calling them with await) to using a queue that is concurrent? I feel like both ways produce the same effect, the function call executes on a different thread until it is finished..
Also I still don't understand why it's not possible to use a synchonous thread to sort of "append" functions to run once the thread becomes unblocked.

Comment: Queue works with threads async await uses actor's, there are very similar but not the same (actor != thread). Concurrency as a whole replaces the old methods. You haven't provided a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if an MRE is too much work for you a full answer with code is too much for most people that answer questions on here. I would just be speculating on your setup, give a solution a try and if you have kinks I don't mind helping but I don't write code for  people. SO isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Swift concurrency is well suited for handling dependencies between tasks that are, themselves, asynchronous. We could wrap the first `async` function call in a `Task`, and then later `await` the result of that `Task`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(viewModel.results)
            Button("Example 1 - update") { viewModel.update() }
            Button("Example 2 - fetch")  { viewModel.fetch() }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var results = ""

    var task: Task<Void, Never>?

    let example1 = Example1ManagerState()
    let example2 = Example2ManagerState()

    func update() {
        task = Task {
            results = "starting update"
            let updateResults = await example1.update()
            results = updateResults
        }
    }

    func fetch() {
        Task {
            _ = await task?.result
            results = "starting fetch"
            let fetchResults = await example2.fetch()
            results = fetchResults
        }
    }
}

actor Example1ManagerState {
    func update() async -> String {
        let seconds: TimeInterval = .random(in: 2...3)
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(seconds))
        return "\(#function) finished \(seconds)"
    }
}

actor Example2ManagerState {
    func fetch() async -> String {
        let seconds: TimeInterval = .random(in: 2...3)
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(seconds))
        return "\(#function) finished \(seconds)"
    }
}
```

Above, I have abstracted the business logic out of the “view” and into a “view model” (with the goal of a better separation of responsibilities, which simplifies unit testing, etc.), but that is unrelated to the broader point. The observation is that whoever is calling `update` and `fetch` should manage the dependencies between these tasks (in this case, the view model has the `Task` property), and that this logic not be incorporated in `Example1ManagerState` or `Example2ManagerState`.

---

A few other random observations:

1. We should generally avoid intermingling GCD API with Swift concurrency’s `async`-`await`. I would advise against using `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}` in Swift concurrency code. In general, this is a bad practice, and in some cases, it can cause serious problems. The compiler is getting better about warning us of this misuse, and is likely to be a hard error in Swift 6.
2. If you are not using Swift concurrency and are considering legacy approaches, a few observations regarding points in your question:

   - `DispatchQueue` is excellent for managing blocks of code added to a queue. And you can dispatch these blocks of code either synchronously (`sync`) or asynchronously (`async`). That synchronous/asynchronous dispatch dictates whether the caller’s thread will be blocked while the dispatched block runs.

     But `DispatchQueue` is only useful if the code inside the dispatched block, itself, runs synchronously. Do not conflate the synchronous/asynchronous nature with respect to the caller  (namely, does the caller wait or not) with the synchronous/asynchonous nature of the code *inside* the dispatched block.

     For example, imagine that you dispatched a `URLSession` `dataTask` to a dispatch queue. That queue will manage the *creation* of those `URLSession` requests, but not the waiting for those asynchronous requests to actually finish. (Lol.)

     In general, avoid using dispatch queues for launching tasks that are, themselves, asynchronous.
   - To solve this problem in legacy codebases, we would turn to operation queues for managing dependencies between tasks that are, themselves, asynchronous. It managed dependencies between asynchronous operations exceptionally well. (When implemented well, it also features excellent separation of responsibilities affording us highly-cohesive, loosely-coupled code.)

     But writing asynchronous `Operation` subclasses is extremely fiddly. Once you set it up, it is a wonderful pattern, but the proper implementation of a custom asynchronous subclass of the `Operation` object is far from intuitive or obvious. E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104095/1271826.)

     Swift concurrency, with `async`-`await`, eliminates all of that ugliness.
   - You mention `DispatchGroup`. That is really intended for establishing dependencies between multiple GCD work items. (E.g., you might want to trigger block of code after a bunch of other dispatched blocks, running in parallel, finish.)

     Because you can manually `enter` and `leave` dispatch groups, we can contort ourselves to use this to manage dependencies between blocks of code that are, themselves, asynchronous, but again, Swift concurrency handles this far more gracefully.
3. Regarding your question about not wanting to pass the legacy object managing the dependencies (i.e., the operation queue, or the dispatch group, or whatever), you are absolutely correct: You would want to avoid that.

   For example, in the operation queue world, rather than passing the operation queue to this other manager object, you would instead refactor the code so that the manager object could vend an operation, and let the caller add it to its own operation queue. That avoids passing the queue about.

   The same is true for the dispatch groups. Rather than passing the `DispatchGroup` object around (at which point it becomes very difficult to diagnose problems, understand dependencies, etc.), you would give the two `ManagerState` methods a completion handler, and the caller would `enter` the group before calling the method and `leave` in the completion handler.

   Bottom line, yes, avoid passing operation queues or dispatch groups or what-have-you around. Just like I have isolated the `Task` dependency in the calling code (the view model in my example), you would do the same in traditional sorts of patterns, avoiding the entangling of dependencies in these manager types, altogether, and letting the caller handle this.

In short, Swift concurrency should do what you need, and get you out of the complexities of these brittle and complicated GCD implementations.

Comment: The main issue I am facing is that "retrieveUpdate" and "fetch" are in a different class, thus don't have access to a shared "task" per-se. I guess your code would work if one injects this task to both classes? I edit the question with a full code example. Also, could you elaborate why one needs the @MainActor?

Comment: Notice, that `update` is in `Foo` and `fetch` is in `Bar`. I'm just having whomever is initiating both of these asynchronous request manage the dependency. Like loremipsum said, you should show us a practical example of what you're trying to do, rather than having us guess. Show us (simplified) code of where you are initiating `update` and where you are initiating `fetch`.

Comment: Re `@MainActor`, this is a view model, whose sole purpose is to publish values for the view. You want that happening on the main actor. I generally have my view models declared as `@MainActor` so I don't have to worry about making sure that the individual `@Published` properties are published on the main actor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great and detailed answer, it helped a ton! I will accept your answer but have just one more question: in my actual project the `update()` function is called from a `didUpdateLocations` function of a `CLLocationManager`. So this function is actually called "by itself" or inside of its class (handling other things related to location). Since you advise not to pass the task to this class, how should I best implement this in my project? I do not see a great way to "isolate the Task dependency in the calling code" while keeping things unrelated separate.

Comment: That's a completely different question (and, if you forgive me for saying it, a perfect example of why you must be more specific in your question): In short, you would create an `AsyncSequence` for it. E.g. [`LocationSequenceManager`](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/e70aef8595fd79ad30f773c876d155a5). Then, you would `await` values yielded by that sequence (e.g., [here](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/07a2a93a4b87fba1290d42df8be2896c) I initiate an manager that performs an asynchronous reverse-geolocation search every time the location manager `AsyncStream` yields a new value).

Comment: Okay. Thanks again and sorry for not being clear. I have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74909125/delaying-function-until-separate-function-has-ended) to better suit my actual problem, hopefully this time it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

According to your example you just need to add one line

```
    Button {
        Task {
            await ex1.update()
            ex2.fetch() // here this line doesn’t run unless update is done
        }
    } label: {
        Text("start long task")
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately my MRE lacked one aspect present in my actual project: the `update()` function is called from a `didUpdateLocations` function of a `CLLocationManager`. Also, the `fetch()`function should be called individually and only await an `update()` to finish if it has been started, otherwise just run without calling the update()` again.

Comment: @D.Kee turn the Location code into true async await code if you get multiple updates you can convert into an `AsyncStream` if not just a regular `async` function.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few different options you can consider to achieve your goal of having the fetch function wait for the update function to finish before executing. Here are some options and their differences:

DispatchQueue: A DispatchQueue is a way to execute tasks either serially (one at a time) or concurrently (at the same time). You can use a serial DispatchQueue to ensure that tasks are executed one at a time in the order they are added to the queue. To use a serial DispatchQueue, you can create your own DispatchQueue and set the attribute .isSerial to true. Alternatively, you can use the .main queue, which is a serial queue that is used to execute tasks on the main thread. However, you cannot use the await keyword with a DispatchQueue, as it is not aware of async/await. Instead, you can use a closure or a function as a task to be executed on the queue.

DispatchGroup: A DispatchGroup allows you to group multiple tasks together and wait for all of them to finish before moving on to the next set of tasks. You can use a DispatchGroup to ensure that the fetch function waits for the update function to finish before executing. To do this, you can add the update function to the DispatchGroup before executing it, and then call DispatchGroup.wait() in the fetch function to wait for the update function to finish before continuing. You will need to pass a reference to the DispatchGroup object to both classes in order to use it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "you can use a closure or a function as a task to be executed on the queue."? The problem is that I cannot provide the other function as a closure because it lives in an entirely different area of my app and I would like to avoid passing this function through my whole app somehow.. And if I add both functions as Tasks as I said, the second Task does not wait for the first to finish. Ideally: could you provide a code example?