# delaying function until separate function has ended

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, concurrency

In short, I have a function that is called by a `CLLocationManager` and takes a while to update things on the server.
In the UI a function `fetch()` can be triggered. This should run **after** the `update()` has finished. Thus, if there is no `update()` running, right away.
Further, this `fetch()` should **only** run if it was actually triggered by the Button in the view.

(After having asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74878683/calling-two-functions-after-each-other-using-dispatchqueue-dispatchgroup) it turned out I was not specific enough, to the point where the question and its answer did actually not solve my issue.)

Here is a MRE:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

class ExampleManager: ObservableObject {
    func fetch() {
        print("these would be some results")
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @StateObject var example = ExampleManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            example.fetch()
        } label: {
            Text("fetch")
        }
    }
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    // .. necessary stuff of CLLocationManager
    
    private func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) async {
        guard let newLocation: CLLocation = locations.first else { return }
        await update(newLocation: newLocation)
    }
    
    func update(newLocation: CLLocation) async {
        print("1")
        try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000_000)
        print("2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to show the button unless there is something to fetch to begin with. I have a couple of scenarios here:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

class ExampleManager: ObservableObject {
    func fetch() {
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @StateObject var example = ExampleManager()
    
    var body: some View {
//        ProgressView()
//            .onReceive(locationManager.$updated) { updated in
//                example.fetch()
//            }
        if locationManager.updated {
            Button {
                example.fetch()
            } label: {
                Text("fetch")
            }
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var updated = false
    
    private func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) async {
        guard let newLocation: CLLocation = locations.first else { return }
        await update(newLocation: newLocation)
    }
    
    func update(newLocation: CLLocation) async {
        print("1")
        try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000_000_000)
        print("2")
        updated = true
    }
}
```

Comment: This would only solve the issue for the first time of running the `update()` function. However, it should **always** wait for any current `update()` to finish.

Comment: @D.Kee You can reset updated to false after each fetch.